# Модуль threading

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность

Мне нужно запустить создание двух архивов в двух потоках, для это я использую модуль `threading`.
Проблема заключается в том, что я создаю SFX архив с помощью WinRAR и мне необходимо передать в `args` строку, но Thread это не корректно обрабатывает и выдает ошибку
`TypeError: start_sfx_archiving() takes 1 positional argument but 99 were given`
Сам тестовый код:

```
import os
from subprocess import call
from threading import Thread


def start_sfx_archiving(cmdlinerargs):
    call(["C:/Program Files (x86)/WinRAR/Rar.exe"] + cmdlinerargs.split())


cmdliners1 = "a -v20*1024 -sfx D:/TestingArchiving/archive1 D:/Downloads/Guys/The.Boys.S01E03.rus.LostFilm.TV.avi"
thread1 = Thread(target=start_sfx_archiving, args=cmdliners1)
thread1.start()
thread1.join()
```

Как заставить `Thread` корректно обрабатывать `cmdliners1`?

Comment: Дайте более точный заголовок вопросу

Comment: потоки в python лучше вообще не использовать, интерпретатор всё равно не может больше 1 потока одновременно выполнять =). И что вам не понятно в описании ошибки?

Comment: `Thread(target=start_sfx_archiving, args=(cmdliners1,))`

Comment: @Inventor, в каком плане лучше не использовать? Сколько тестов не делал, всегда 2-4 потока гораздо быстрее выполняют задачу, чем 1 поток.

Comment: @5c0rp Спасибо большое, вроде уже пробовал такой вариант, но именно сейчас заработало)

Comment: @AlexandrKiselev несколько потоков в данном случае быстрее одного, потому что в вашем коде есть моменты, когда интерпретатор простаивает и ничего не делает (обращение к другой программе).  В этом случае лучше использовать асинхронный код в одном потоке, это намного быстрее синхронного кода в нескольких потоках

Comment: `В этом случае лучше использовать асинхронный код в одном потоке, это намного быстрее синхронного кода в нескольких потоках` мягко говоря, это 
 очень спорное утверждение. В данном случае узкое место - это сама архивация, асинхронность тут никак ничего не ускорит.